# How to find elapsed years from a date? javascript

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code to find the years between now and a date, but it is giving me 3.916 instead of 4.001ish. Why is this off so much? The math seems fine and everything else looks good... Thanks!

```js
const year = 1000*60*60*24*365.25;
var now = new Date();
var bDay = new Date(2018, 12, 22);
var elapsedT = now - bDay;
let years = elapsedT / year;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = years;
```

```html
<p>Calculate the number of years since Wedding:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not 4 because your `bDay` date is actually January 22nd, 2019.

This is because the month is 0-indexed, so `12` actually means January of the next year. December would be `11`:

```js
const year = 31540000000;
var now = new Date();
var bDay = new Date(2018, 11, 22);
var elapsedT = now - bDay;
let years = elapsedT / year;
console.log(years)
```

Although it would be much more simple to use `getFullYear` to calculate the year difference:

```js
const year = 31540000000;
var now = new Date();
var bDay = new Date(2018, 11, 22);
let years = now.getFullYear() - bDay.getFullYear()
console.log(years)
```